# Passenger on Apache2 - how to make a site appear on root

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, mongrel

I'm new to apache2 and passenger to set-up rails apps and followed a tutorial on how to get redmine (rails app) set up (http://xdissent.com/2010/05/04/github-clone-with-redmine/).

It all works great but to access the app you need to go to the /redmine directory. I have set it up as redmine.local/redmine. It would be great if I could be just redmine.local.

I had a look through the files I set up as part of the apache/mongrel/passenger piece and took out references to the directory but alas its never that easy.

I would appreciate any assistance, or links to more information for beginners that I can learn from.

Thanks for your help!
Adam

---

***--- Updated ---***

Some additional details, I have the following files which i made edits too as part of the set-up of the server:

/etc/apache2/conf.d/redmine

```
 Include /opt/redmine/apps/redmine/conf/redmine.conf
```

/opt/redmine/apps/redmine/conf/redmine.conf

```
 ProxyPass /redmine balancer://redminecluster
 ProxyPassReverse /redmine balancer://redminecluster

 <Proxy balancer://redminecluster>
   BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001/redmine
   BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002/redmine
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
 </Proxy>
```

/opt/redmine/apps/redmine/config/mongrel_cluster.yml

```
 --- 
 prefix: /redmine
 log_file: log/mongrel.log
 port: "3001"
 environment: production
 pid_file: tmp/pids/mongrel.pid
 servers: 2
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

 <Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
 <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
 </Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
 <Directory /var/www/usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
 <Directory /var/www/usr/share/doc/>
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
 </Directory>
 DocumentRoot /var/www

 </VirtualHost>
```

I can't find a file that references the current directory /redmine as a route so not sure the server finds it in the first place - unless its that conf.d thing.

Comment: what does your apache config look like?

Comment: How would i find that out? I'm using webmin for a lot of this (cheating I know) to avoid being stuck by lack of command knowledge.

Comment: @luckytaxi - I've added the file details I could find the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

1. Edit the `redmine.conf` file to the belows content:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName redmine.local
       ErrorLog logs/redmine_error_log

       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://redminecluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L] 

       <Proxy balancer://redminecluster>
           BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
           BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002
       </Proxy>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Remove the `prefix` option from `mongrel_cluster.yml`.
3. Restart Apache and try again.

Comment: I tried putting just this in my virtual host file but apache woudn't start. I tried adding it via webmin and it links to the directory but just displays the directory content - it doesn't recognize it as an app.

Comment: okay, i updated the redmine.conf, and the mongrel_cluster file. I wasn't sure what you wanted me to do with your original suggestion of the virtual host, so I tried adding that to the end of the default file in the available sites directory. That didn't work, so I tried deleting everything in that file and just having what you had above, that didn't work, then I tried integrating the two - which failed. I update the dir in the virtual host you game me above as my rails app is in /opt/redmine/apps/redmine/public but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: I get the following error when trying to restart apache:
Syntax error on line 5 of /opt/redmine/apps/redmine/conf/redmine.conf:
Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: It means that you haven't loaded the `mod_rewrite` module.

Comment: I've started the mod_rewrite module, and when i changed the redmine.conf back to the original the server starts, but using the one you outlined above the server cannot start, just says fail. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the error log.

Comment: OK - looks like the error was log related- it couldn't find it. So I created a blank log and pointed too it. That solved the restart error.

Now I'm getting a permission error i didn't have before: 
In the browser it says:You don't have permission to access / on this server.
In the redmine_log it says: [Tue Nov 01 16:34:59 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.12] client denied by server configuration: proxy:balancer://redminecluster/

Comment: okay fixed it - added the Order deny,allow and Allow from all lines back in, restarted the redmine app and server and it worked. Thanks.